# Applescript to run script in iterm2 tab returns missing value

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile command "pwd"
    end tell
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
end tell
```

The script above returns 'missing value' when it is runned. It works without command "pwd". Does anyone know what is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that *command* fails, however, here is a way that works:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current window
        set myNewTab to create tab with default profile
        tell current session of myNewTab to write text "pwd"
        create tab with default profile
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: nice! you also know how to set tab title?

Comment: @Vincent, RE: "you also know how to set tab title?" --  Looking in the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ for **iTerm2** and the _properties_ of _class_ **tab**, is does not have a `name` _property_. It shows: "**tab** _n_ : A terminal tab" and to its _properties_ is shows "**current session** (session) : The current session in a tab and "**index** (integer) : Index of tab in parent tab view control". -- There is an **Edit Tab Title** _command_  on the **Window** _menu_ in **iTerm2**, so one could resort to **UI Scripting** to change it programmatically.